# Cos'è un "serpentone sotterraneo"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Si decise per il metrò: la brezza gli carezzava il viso nel riemergere dalle scale all'uscita del **serpentone sotterraneo**; un sole sorridente ed eccelso ne accecò la risalita.

Ho cercato "serpentone" su alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire cosa sia questo "serpentone sotterraneo". Una ricerca su Google mi ha fatto vedere che è un'espressione che si usa. Si riferisce forse ai corridoi della metropolitana?

Ecco qui, ad esempio, la  [voce sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI18/00749.jpg).

Comment: I'd say it's a metaphor to indicate a long mazy tunnel.

Comment: Serpentone è un accrescitivo di serpente, quindi un grosso serpente. Nota di grammatica per il titolo della tua domanda: sarebbe più giusto "che cosa è ..." invece di "cosa è". Compara queste due frasi: "Che colore ti piace?" e "Colore ti piace?"; non ti sembra che la seconda sia sbagliata? Lo è... similmente sono sbagliate le frasi come "cosa è ...", anche se ormai questa forma scorretta è più comune di quella corretta.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Vedi questo [articolo della Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/cosa-o-che-cosa-che_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Io l'ho sempre usato e visto usare come metafora per indicare il convoglio della metropolitana, ma secondo me si comporta un po' come metropolitana che per sineddoche rappresenta il convoglio, la rete, il servizio, la stazione, ...

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Comment: Vedo che appare su [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=2smYB8QBzMgC&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=metro+serpentone&source=bl&ots=-LA8e-YsHm&sig=ACfU3U1l5FHfT7gPQ34yT3chaggIlAOE5Q&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwid7bLdnannAhX4DmMBHVOzBocQ6AEwCnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=metro%20serpentone&f=false), su quest'[altro](https://books.google.es/books?id=34ZJDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT190&lpg=PT190&dq=metro+serpentone&source=bl&ots=tjz_sO7ZHU&sig=ACfU3U05YzOHOLEI2M_HGObUCsNc8SOqKA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs-Ju2nqnnAhUvAWMBHYnpC7M4ChDoATADegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=metro%20serpentone&f=false)...

Comment: ... e anche su [quest'altro](https://books.google.es/books?id=ZetGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT122&lpg=PT122&dq=metro+serpentone&source=bl&ots=oOojpmLxOf&sig=ACfU3U1rwxc84KUDkDtEezm7xfWr3CVaRw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs-Ju2nqnnAhUvAWMBHYnpC7M4ChDoATAIegQIChAB#v=onepage&q=metro%20serpentone&f=false).

Comment: È un’immagine (quindi non un sinonimo), per rendere facilmente l’idea di qualcosa di lungo, che si muove “scivolando” e facendo delle curve. Si può usare anche per dire una lunga coda di macchine sulle strade del rientro in città la domenica sera (dopo il fine settimana).